# Can I use ScrollView instead of Container View?

Tags: java, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

export default class Video extends Component {
render() {
return (

```
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>   
            <ImageBackground source={require('../asset/Video-Img.jpg')}
                style={styles.bgImg}>
                <MaterialIcon name="play-circle-outline" size={55} color={'#fff'} />
            </ImageBackground>
```

This is how i execute my code instead of Container View. Any problem will happen with this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use scrollview instead of view

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion but if developing for iOS, I would wrap the entire `ScrollView` within `SafeAreaView`.

```
<SafeAreaView>
   <ScrollView style={styles.container}>   
        <ImageBackground source={require('../asset/Video-Img.jpg')}
            style={styles.bgImg}>
            <MaterialIcon name="play-circle-outline" size={55} color= 
            {'#fff'} />
        </ImageBackground>
   </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Why?

> The purpose of SafeAreaView is to render content within the safe area
> boundaries of a device. It is currently only applicable to iOS devices
> with iOS version 11 or later.

But `ScrollView` as you have is perfectly fine to do so.  Just be sure to read up on the **documentation** - especially the part in the first paragraph relating to the height.

Also, depending on how much content you are displaying - it may have an impact on performance.

> ScrollView renders all its react child components at once, but this
> has a performance downside.

If you are looking to just list items, consider FlatList.

> This is where FlatList comes into play. FlatList renders items lazily,
> when they are about to appear, and removes items that scroll way off
> screen to save memory and processing time.

> FlatList is also handy if you want to render separators between your
> items, multiple columns, infinite scroll loading, or any number of
> other features it supports out of the box.